# Prove that if $\{A,B\}$ is independent then so it $\{A^c,B\}$

Tags: probability

I was asked to prove that if $\{A,B\}$ is independent then so it $\{A^c,B\}$. Is this a typo? Shouldn't it be $\{A^c,B^c\}$?

Comment: Well, try to prove the given statement and see what happens.

Comment: If $\{A,B\}$ are independent then $A\cap B = \emptyset$ so then $A^c \cap B \neq \emptyset$ meaning that $P(A^c|B)=\frac{A^c \cap B}{P(B)}\neq 0$ so the two events are not independent? Is this correct?

Comment: @MathematicalDummy -- no, if they are disjoint then $A\cap B=\emptyset$ -- independent events have just the right type of intersection

Comment: Mutually exclusive events are not independent!  Knowing that one happened is proof that the other did not (ignoring some complications when one or the other event has probability $0$ but is still possible).

Comment: If the pair of events $\{A,B\}$ are independent then so are the pairs $\{A^c,B\}$ and  $\{A,B^c\}$ and $\{A^c,B^c\}$

Comment: On the distinction between *independent* and *mutually disjoint*, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/380791/2958 may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: No, not a typo :)

If $A,B$ are independent events then $P(A|B) =  P(A)$ or $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$

However, we also know that $P(A^c) = 1-P(A)$

Ask yourself -- if you know that if $B$ happened then $A$ will happen with $P(A)$, don't you also know the probability it will *not* happen? Does this event behave like an independent event too?

Comment: Thank you, I now understand the logic that if I know the probability of $A$ given $B$ then I also know the probability of $A^c$ given $B$. Is the way to do this formally: If $P(A|B)=P(A)$ then $P(A^c|B)+P(A|B)=1 \Rightarrow P(A^c|B)+P(A)=1 \Rightarrow  P(A^c|B)=1-P(A)=P(A^c)$?

Comment: @MathematicalDummy bingo! :) You've shown that $A^c$ satisfies the definition of an independent event relative to $B$